# Scala MapType and Tuple as KeyValue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know that in Scala MapTypes are defined as

```
public MapType(DataType keyType,
               DataType valueType,
               boolean valueContainsNull)
```

But I don't know how to use a Tuple as keyType, since allowed DataTypes are

```
Direct Known Subclasses:
ArrayType, BinaryType, BooleanType, CalendarIntervalType, DateType, HiveStringType, MapType, NullType, NumericType, ObjectType, StringType, StructType, TimestampType
```

How can I use a Tuple as keyType for a MapType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tuple type" is a `StructType` so for example `(String, Double)` is a struct:

```
StructType(Seq(
  StructField("_1", StringType, true),
  StructField("_2", DoubleType, false)))
```

where fields are enumerated using `StructField` objects.

Please remember that schema is typically applicable for `Row` objects:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("map", MapType(
     StructType(Seq(
       StructField("_1", StringType, true),
        StructField("_2", DoubleType, false))),
     LongType))))

spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(Map(Row("foo", 1.1D) -> 1L)))),
  schema
)
```

If data is stronly typed, there is no need for schema

```
spark.createDataFrame(Seq(Tuple1(Map(( "foo", 1.1D) -> 1L))))
```

and mixed strongly / weak typed objects are not supported:

```
spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(Map(( "foo", 1.1D) -> 1L)))),
  schema
)
```

Comment: If I define the map as `myMap = (("foo", 1.1D) -> 1L)`, using your exact StructType the following exception is raised: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of struct<_1:string,_2:double>`